# Oh gush, it's too early to go to bed

Tags: phrase-meaning

---

-Eddie stopped, made a quick look round the hall. “I am not walking away from you, you know. I just felt tired and wanted to go to my bed. You get what I mean?” ***he said softly***.

-“**Oh gush**, it's too early to go to bed, man. You should not run away from the fun at this early hour.” ***Obusah told him***.

---

What does "**Oh, gush**" mean? Does it mean"**Oh my god**" or something else?

Comment: What is the source? It's probably meant to be "gosh".

Comment: Source: https://books.google.nl/books?id=c4zS4jbIuLwC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22oh+gush%22+MEANS&source=bl&ots=1na0PlSHMg&sig=ACfU3U2IrXK9DbLJE-Nzp8ZW6KgLNdDAYQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk4IuJq8vvAhVyxoUKHSEQB0gQ6AEwDHoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22oh%20gush%22%20MEANS&f=false

Comment: The text is full of errors, so I wouldn't worry about the exact meaning. https://books.google.com/books?id=c4zS4jbIuLwC&dq="oh+gush"+MEANS&q=oh+gush#v=snippet&q=oh%20gush&f=false shows the author is just using it as a mild exclamation similar to "[Oh gosh](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/oh+gosh)".

Comment: Wow. That book is in serious need of editing. There is no idiom "Oh, gush." Also, it's a good principle to not learn grammar from erotica.